# OfficeLive email settings - Authorization Failed

Tags: microsoft-office, email, office-live

Is there anybody who tried creating emails with **Microsoft's OfficeLive**

I wonder how to add a created office live e-mail to Outlook?
By e.g.

my LiveId is `me@gmail.com`, password: `pmegmailcom`
officeLive site: `www.mysite.com`,
email: `contact@mysite.com`, password: `pcontactmysitecom`

**I do new mail account in Outlook:**

Your name: MySiteTeam; Email address: `contact@mysite.com`
Incoming mail server: `pop3.live.com`; Outgoing mail server: `smtp.live.com`
User Name: `me@gmail.com`; Password: `pmegmailcom`
My outgoing server requires authentication - *Yes*
Use same settings as my incoming mail server - *Yes*
Pop3 port: `995` (SSL - *Yes*), Smtp port: `587` (SSL - *Yes*)

In fact, I follow the following [office live forum moderators instructions](http://ask.officelive.com/smallbusiness/qna/p/13311/33791.aspx#33791).

**When testing finds POP3 server, finds SMTP server, does not pass authorization.**

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, find the "trick". I needed to log out from office live, then relog-in with the new live-id based on the newly created e-mail.

There you need to change (why?!) your old password to a new one. 
After creating a new Windows Live Id, your mail box is ready, and you log-in (in Outlook too) with `contact@mysite.com`, `pcontactmysitecomNEW`;

Finally, You receive a "Welcome to Hotmail" (?!) and should be happy.

Answer (score 0):

> My outgoing server requires authentication - *Yes*

Have you tried setting this to *No*?

All outgoing servers I've encountered don't require authentication.

Comment: the same thing: server does not accept username/password. I follow these instructions: http://ask.officelive.com/smallbusiness/qna/p/13311/33791.aspx#33791